# New line not recognized by Twilio in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-4, twilio, twilio-php

Using PHP/Laravel.
And the latest Twilio library 5.16.2

Followed this - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181468-How-do-I-add-a-line-break-in-my-SMS-message-

And none of these work, they are sent as it is:

- %0a
- \n
- %0D%0A

> $textMessageToSend = $textMessageToSend . ' %0a ' .
>   $emailLinkOfContent;

What am I missing ?

Comment: You need to use Double quoted string to get line breaks

Comment: `\n` is taken literally if expressed in single quotes, make sure you use `"\n"`

Comment: any reason for a down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the single quoted string use Double quotes to solve the issue,

```
$textMessageToSend = $textMessageToSend . "%0a" . $emailLinkOfContent;
```

make sure `$textMessageToSend` and `$emailLinkOfContent` are both strings assigned with double quotes if initialisation is hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Twilio in Laravel about 2 months ago and I had no problem with sending SMS with content like this:

```
'Test'. "\n" .'new line'
```

it went to new line where it should but as you see in PHP you should use double quotes for new line to make it work.